# How to close the tab with a message that "the file does not exist anymore" in c# win form application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a notepad with a tabbed interface. It is a c# winform application. Now, what I want is this - if the file does not exist anymore, deleted by another program then if I click the related tab, it should show a message that "the file does not exist" and it should close the tab.

Comment: what part of your code are you stuck on ? Can you show it to us please

Comment: I have uploaded the code. See below.

Comment: you should not put any code or other information in an answer, but you should EDIT your original question and put all new info in there. You cannot expect anyone to search this page and collect all info from different places

Answer (score 0):

```
private string FolderPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); // location of document folder

 private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        if (tabControl1.TabCount == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {

            TabPage tpp = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
            this.FileOnly = tpp.Text + ".txt"; // I used tab names without extension, that's why adding it back
            String str = tpp.Text;
            string CorrFolderPath = FolderPath.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
            string FolderPathcomplete = CorrFolderPath + "\\My_Note\\"; // this is the location of saving files; the folder contents appear as list box entries in the program
            string filename = FolderPathcomplete + FileOnly;
            if (str.Contains("New Document"))// the new tabs which are not yest saved has the name New Document 1, 2 etc.
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (File.Exists(filename))
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File does not exist! Closing the tab.");
                    var tabPage = tabControl1.TabPages[str];
                    tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveByKey(str);

                }
            }
        }
    }


private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tp = new TabPage("New Document" + count); //creates a new tab page
        tp.Name = "New Document" + count;
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox(); //creates a new richtext box object

        tp.Controls.Add(rtb); // adds rich text box to the tab page
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp); //adds the tab pages to tab control
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tp;
        tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged; // it will check whether tab file exists or not
        this.FileName = string.Empty;
        count++;

    }
```

Comment: How does this answers your question?

Comment: tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged; this line is the key. To use this line, you have to define the tabControl1_SelectdIndexChanged first.

Comment: is it actually possible to get into a `SelectedIndexChanged` event when there are no tabs ?

Comment: Well, I am a newbie to C# programming. But I think `SelectedIndexCanged` can only be accessed when there is a tab. I am not sure. But if you have a single text file scenario, then there is an option TextChanged. You can use it to detect any change in a rich text box, and you can tell it to do what you want to do in response to that (like appending a star at the end of the file name).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a FileSystemWatcher -- where on creation of a new tab, you create a new watcher and monitor for any changes.

See this article for more information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I solved it! See below! It is working fine! Thanks for sharing the link.